# What is the antonym of "boldface"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Is it nonboldface? Is bold's antonym nonbold? Is it unemboldened? Is it hyphenated? What word do I use to mean text that is not in boldface style?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_weight#Weight

Comment: *Boldface, italic, underlined,* etc., are all variations to "normal" type, so that's effectively the antonym for all of them. If you really need an antonym for *boldface*, it should probably be *non-boldface*, but most people would be glad to settle for *non-bold*.

Comment: I have seen *lightface* used for *not boldface*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Roman* is the technical term for non-bold, non-italic.

Bold refers to the weight of a typeface. A non-bold typeface, regardless of any other properties, is called *light*.

Comment: You're biased! I can tell by your name.

Comment: @tenfour: What do you mean?

Comment: @CesarGon: Julius Caesar was a Roman :)

Comment: According to Wikipedia, apparently the following are acceptable: Normal / regular / roman / plain

Comment: @Hugo, tenfour: Oh, I see. Duh.

Answer (score 3):

I would call this type of text **simple** or **plain**. However, I don't think this is an antonym for **boldface**. It is just text which isn't bold-faced, italicised or underlined.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the answers given above, I would like to provide one. A Non-bold type face is often also called as a **regular** type face.